# Why a derived class B is said not to be a member of its parent class A?

Tags: c++, class

I do not understand why the following code does not work since `*p` is dynamically a `B` object.

```
class A {
public:
    bool test() {return true;}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    bool test() {return false;}
};

int main() {
    A* p = new B;
    std::cout << p->B::test();
    return 0;
}
```

I know I could use `virtual` but I believe this is not the point. The compiler says I should define a second constructor or a conversion operator. What can I do ?

Comment: A) Try and include the *exact* compiler messages you're getting in the question. B) If you're overriding you do need `virtual` so it can properly populate the vtable. If you don't it just maps functions based on the type, which is `A*`.

Comment: It is possible for `A*` to not point to a `B*`, so as a general rule you cannot use `B::test()` with a `A*`. If you are sure `p` points to a `B` you can use `dynamic_cast` like `dynamic_cast<B*>(p)->test();`. Edit : Or you could if `A` was polymorphic. You can use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `dynamic_cast` works only with polymorphism and `A` and `B` are not

Comment: @bolov You must have missed my edit.

Comment: The compiler is complaining because `B` is not a member of `A`. Just look at the definition of `A`. It’s that simple.

Comment: Shouldn't the test() in A be virtual?

Comment: Pointers and where they are pointing is a run-time thing, so the compiler can't really know what a pointer might be pointing at. Therefore it can't handle your code.

Answer (score 2):

`*p` is dynamically a `B` object, but with declaration `A* p` and usage `p->test()`, `A::test()` is statically linked at compile time.

If you want dynamic dispatch at runtime, you have to use `virtual` functions.

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
public:
        bool test() { return true; }
        virtual int count() { return 42; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
        bool test() { return false; }
        virtual int count() { return 100; }
};

int main() {
        A* p = new B();
        std::cout << p->test() << std::endl; // A::test() is called
        std::cout << p->count(); // B::count() is called
}
```

In the example, functions `bool test()` will be dispatched statically, while `int count()` will be dispatched dynamically.